# Fast way to calculate product over one dimension of a 3D array in R

Tags: arrays, r, performance, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I have a three dimensional array (e.g. dimensions = 4000 x 4000 x 2). Now I'd like to calculate the product over the third dimension to obtain a two dimensional array (dimensions = 4000 x 4000) as a result.

I tried to calculate the product using `prod()` within the the `apply()` function; however this is quite time consuming. Thus, I am wondering if there is a faster and more efficient way for such calculations?

The `apply()` approach:

```
A <- array(runif(4000*4000*2),dim=c(4000,4000,2))
system.time(apply(A, c(1,2), prod))
```

Here a smaller example with array `B`:

```
B <- array(c(1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4),dim=c(2,2,2))
```

with the results `B_res`:

```
B_res <-  array(c(3,3,8,8),dim=c(2,2))
```

*Update:*
As mentioned by @42- this could be done by element wise (manual) multiplication, like: `B_res <- B[,,1]*B[,,2]`. However, the size of the third dimension might range from 2 to x. So manually coding `B[,,1]*B[,,2]... *B[,,x]` might not be feasible. Here a loop calculating in a loop might be one possible solution:

```
array_prod <- function(C){
  C_res <- C[,,1]
  for(i in 2:dim(C)[3]){
    C_res <- C_res*C[,,i]
  }
  return(C_res)
}
```

Here a comparison of the three approaches (apply, manual element-wise and loop multiplication):

```
A <- array(runif(400*400*10),dim=c(400,400,10))
system.time(apply(A, c(1,2), prod)); system.time(A[,,1]*A[,,2]*A[,,3]*A[,,4]*A[,,5]*A[,,6]*A[,,7]*A[,,8]*A[,,9]*A[,,10]); system.time(array_prod(A))
  user  system elapsed 
  0.492   0.021   0.512 
   user  system elapsed 
  0.031   0.000   0.032 
   user  system elapsed 
  0.032   0.001   0.032
```

...which shows that the apply function is significatnly slower than the other two approaches which are basically similarily fast.

Comment: You should post an example of a 3x3x2 array and say what the right answer might be. If it's just elementwise mult then just `A[,,1]*A[,,2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This demonstrates that elementwise array multiplication is accomplished using what in R is called a vectorised approach by leaving the first two dimensions empty and using the `*` operator. Can also put TRUE to signify all instances of a particular dimension:

```
A <- array( 1:(4*4*2),dim=c(4,4,2))
apply(A, c(1,2), prod)
#============
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   17  105  225  377
[2,]   36  132  260  420
[3,]   57  161  297  465
[4,]   80  192  336  512
#=============
A[ , , 1]*A[ , , 2]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   17  105  225  377
[2,]   36  132  260  420
[3,]   57  161  297  465
[4,]   80  192  336  512
```

And this shows the 100-fold improvement in performance (Although I tired of waiting for the 4000x4000 version of apply to run so I only show the results with the vectorized approach on that example:)

```
> A <- array(runif(400*400*2),dim=c(400,400,2))
> system.time(apply(A, c(1,2), prod)); system.time(A[,,1]*A[,,2])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.448   0.018   0.452   # the apply timings
   user  system elapsed 
  0.005   0.000   0.004   # the vectorised operation

> A <- array(runif(4000*4000*2),dim=c(4000,4000,2))
>  system.time(A[,,1]*A[,,2])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.525   0.096   0.604
```